# Python buttons not appearing in Blender

Tags: scripting, python

I'm still very new to Blender, but I'm trying to get a custom menu up and running.
I followed the video tutorial on Blender Cookie and works great.

I'm trying to create a button that will move and object to the origin.

My code is as followed.

```
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator("transform.resize", text="Scale")
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator("context.active_object.location=(0,0,0)", text="Orgin")
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator("transform.translate(value=(0,0,0))", text="Orgin")
```

The "Scale" button works so I know something somewhat works. The other two buttons do not show up. I was trying to see what move commands work.

I tried the commands independently in the console and they work... just not in button form.

Comment: Try moving the translate command to the top, and see how many buttons appear, and whether the command works. Also try making three scale buttons. In the console, type `help(layout.row);` and `help(row.operator)`. I strongly suspect you need to specify a function _name_, not a statement (such as a function _call_ or an assignment). But also make sure you're using `layout.row` correctly.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `context.active_object.location=(0,0,0)` is not an operator. It's a statement.

You could define your own operator:

```
import bpy
def main(context):
    # This is what happens when your operator is invoked.
    context.active_object.location = (0, 0, 0)

class SnapToCenterOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Snaps an object to the center."""
    bl_idname = "view3d.snap_to_center_operator"
    bl_label = "Snap Object to Center"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        # This is called to determine whether the operator can be invoked
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        # This invokes the operator and returns a state
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    # If it's an addon, this is called when the addon is enabled
    bpy.utils.register_class(SnapToCenterOperator)
def unregister():
    # If it's an addon, this is called when the addon is disabled
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SnapToCenterOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # We use this to register it in case we're running it manually
    # (which we are; click the "Run Script" button)
    register()
```

and then use

```
row.operator("view3d.snap_to_center", text="Origin")
```

to achieve the desired result.

---

**NOTE:** This is just an example on how to create your own operator. In this case you'll [actually just want to use](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3445/python-buttons-not-appearing-in-blender/3459?noredirect=1#comment5898_3459) `bpy.ops.object.location_clear`, as such:

```
row.operator("object.location_clear", text="Origin")
```

Comment: Downvoter, please explain?

Answer (score 4):

Function `row`.[`operator()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.operator) only accepts [operators](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.ops.html), the full name of which are prefixed with `bpy.ops.`, as in [`bpy.ops.transform.resize`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.ops.transform.html#bpy.ops.transform.resize) for the 1st row. The 2nd row fails because it's not an operator.

The mechanism for passing arguments to an operator is by using the [`OperatorProperties`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.OperatorProperties.html#bpy.types.OperatorProperties) object returned by `operator()`. So, the 3rd row could be rewritten like this:

```
row = layout.row()
prop = row.operator("transform.translate", text="Orgin")
prop.value = (1, 0, 0)
```

Note that your original `value` argument of `(0, 0, 0)` wouldn't move the object anywhere, as if it fails to execute. The `value` I use above will move it 1 unit across X axis.

Comment: but that wouldn't move it to the origin; the only way to really do it like this would be to set `prop.value` to some tricky lambda that overrides `__getitem__` to check `bpy.context.active_object.location[0] * -1` or similar.

Comment: Whoops, didn't realize that bit about moving to origin. In that case, [`object.location_clear()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.location_clear) might be more appropriate.

Comment: ah, indeed! Didn't know that existed.

Comment: You can also use row.operator('transform.translate', text='Origin').value=(1, 0, 0) instead of putting the value assignment on two lines

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is convenient to use the `bpy.ops.wm.context_*` operators to change context properties, as you don't need to create your own operator to wrap single-liners.

```
# Operator call
bpy.ops.wm.context_set_value(data_path="object.location", value="(1,2,3)")

# Add to layout
props = row.operator("wm.context_set_value", text="Orgin")
props.data_path = "object.location"
props.value = "(0,0,0)"

# data_path can be any member of bpy.context
# If it's not available, the operator will PASS_THROUGH
```